# How to edit Parquet file header programmatically or using editor?

Tags: parquet

Using  parquet-tools I can view header but I dont have a way to edit.

`parquet-tools head file.parquet`

Do we have a way to edit the header using java code programmatically or using editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parquet files are immutable, so if you need to modify a file you generally need to create a new file with the modifications and replace the old file with it.

Comment: Thank you !! Any pointers around how to create a new file from existing file with edits on header?